# Identify common objects

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I have recently started using Neo4J. To load the existing data from mongo to Neo4j, I started using mongo-connector which uses Neo4J Doc Manager

But the problem I find here is the following: 
Lets say I have 2 documents in mongo:

Doc 1 : {"title":"Associate","_id":"title_1","technicalSkills":[{"name":"Accounting Associate","score":0.5482839345932007,"_id":"skill_1"}]}

Doc 2 : {"title":"Associate Level 2","_id":"title_2","technicalSkills":[{"_id":"skill_1","name":"Accounting Associate","score":0.65},{"name":"Lead Home Health Care Company","score":0.5077081322669983,"_id":"skill_2"}]}

When we run mongo-connector it will insert in neo4j, two title nodes and each node has its own skill nodes. But if you see, there is a common skill between the two title nodes. The question I have here is:

1. Is there a way to have only one skill node which is common to both docs and then connect this node to both title nodes.
2. Can we have score instead of the relation? (In this case, it creates relations like title_skill).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two mongo-collections and use cross-collections references. For example `skills` and `associates`:

```
db.skills.insert({ "name": "Accounting Associate", 
                   "_id": "skill_1"
});
db.skills.insert({ "name": "Lead Home Health Care Company",
                   "_id": "skill_2"
});

db.associates.insert({ "title":"Associate",
                       "_id":"title_1",
                       "technicalSkills":[{ "skills_id": "skill_1"
                                            "score": 0.5482839345932007
                       }]
});

db.associates.insert({ "title":"Associate Level 2",
                       "_id":"title_2",
                       "technicalSkills":[{ "skills_id": "skill_1",
                                            "score": 0.65},
                                          { "skills_id": "skill_2",
                                            "score": 0.5077081322669983 
                       }]
});
```